# how to execute an action after allow button is pressed in the location access permission?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

[image]

I am making an app that uses coordinate from GPS, before implementing it, we have to ask permission to the user like the picture above.

I want to make if the user tap "allow" at that alert, then  `activateGPSToSearchCoordinate()` is trigerred, but if 'don't allow' is tapped then I don't want to do anything.

this is my code at the moment, and it doesn't work properly

```
class LocationManager: NSObject {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    var didGetLocation: ((Coordinate?) -> Void)?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestLocation()
    }

    func getPermission() -> CLAuthorizationStatus {
        // to ask permission to the user by showing an alert (the alert message is available on info.plist)

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            return .notDetermined
        } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied {
            return .denied
        } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse  {
            return .authorizedWhenInUse
        } else {
            return .notDetermined
        }

    }
}
```

I will use that class in the view controller method like below, especially that `getPermission()`

```
func getCoordinate() {


        let coordinateAuthorizationStatus = locationManager.getPermission()

        if coordinateAuthorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            activateGPSToSearchCoordinate()
        } else if coordinateAuthorizationStatus == .denied {
            showAlertSetting()
        }

    }
```

at the moment, if that permission is triggered for the very first time...
either the user tap 'Allow' or 'don't Allow' the `CLAuthorizationStatus` will always be `.notDetermined`

so the `activateGPSToSearchCoordinate()` , will never be triggered.

so I need to to activate `activateGPSToSearchCoordinate()` only after the 'Allow' at that alert is pressed

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Read more about [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate), there is delegate methods for Success and failure.

```
public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    GlobalObjects.shared.latitude  = locations[0].coordinate.latitude
    GlobalObjects.shared.longtitude = locations[0].coordinate.longitude
    GlobalObjects.shared.locationOBJ = locations[0]
    print(GlobalObjects.shared.latitude, GlobalObjects.shared.longtitude)
}

public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate)? Did you try this?

```
func locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations: [CLLocation])
//Tells the delegate that new location data is available.


func locationManager(CLLocationManager, didFailWithError: Error)
//Tells the delegate that the location manager was unable to retrieve a location value.


func locationManager(CLLocationManager, didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError: Error?)
//Tells the delegate that updates will no longer be deferred.


func locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateTo: CLLocation, from: CLLocation)
//Tells the delegate that a new location value is available.
```

Implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, on a class/view controller from where you are calling `func getCoordinate()`.

```
class TestViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       locationManager.delegate = self
    }


}

public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // get location coordinate
}

public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
   // handle error, if any kind of error occurs
}
```

Here are nice tutorial with example, may help you, in implementing `CLLocationManagerDelegate` :

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/160517/mapkit-tutorial-getting-started
- https://www.appcoda.com/tag/mapkit/
- http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Swift_Example_iOS_8_Location_Application